# Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator Scale

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm testing Visual Studio 2015's ability to develop Cordova applications.

I am using  "Google Android Emulator" as a target and while the emulator loads, it's too big for the screen I am developing on.

I understand I can pass a scale argument when loading the emulator myself (via command line or AVD), however I do not know how to provide this argument via Visual Studio 2015, so the question:

How do I set the scale of the Google Android Emulator instance created from VS2015?

Comment: Yes. I need to know how to scale an emulator when launched from VS2015 as well.